# Python: Logical error in recursion under double for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, recursion, python-itertools

**BackGround**

I am working on a project where I need to compare a set of strings and only keep the ones that are `unique` or `distinct`. 
`Uniq` or `distinct` means no two strings should be,
A) Palindromes , e.g. `ABA' , 'BCB'

B) Reverse of each other. e.g.`'ABCD'`and '`DCBA'
`C) Same as each other, e.g.`'ABC'`and`'ABC'`

If the list does contain such attributes, then program should only keep one of them and remove other.

For e.g. I am using `itertools` and `permutations` and `combination` modules to generate a list as below,
`aList= ['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA', 'ABC']`

And process it through two for loops.
Outer for loop processes each number from start to end until `End of List -1` item is hit.
Inner for loop processes from  `start + 1` item to `End of List`.
This way the two loops are always comparing  two different strings.

*Now, The need is to get this logic done using* **`Recursions`.**

**What Works**

I did write following program that calls in recursion function every time the attributes are found and the duplicate items are removed.

**What Doesn't Work**

The recursion works only if there is at least one item within list that matches attribute criteria and is deleted. When the `saveFound = True`. I used another variable to track partial finds using `found = True` as well,but haven't quite got to make it work.

The program fails when there are no matching attribute within list for a particular item. However, we are not done until all the items are checked and we are down to last two items within list. Then we exit.

**What I need help with**

I've put extra print statements (*ending in #debug*) to see what item are being replaced.
I need to know how  the recursive function can be used in the program to fix the situation where, when there are no duplicates with respect to first item. The program is doing self comparison and removing  itself from the list.
Looks like its not reaching outer for loop for this situation.
Any input / fix is appreciated.

**Program:**

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

""" Process list to generate Unique strings matching given criteria """
def uniqLst(aList):

    """ Iterate through outer loop to compare each string until End of Loop """
    firstItem = 0
    lastItem = len(aList) -1
    for item1 in aList[firstItem:lastItem:]:

        saveFound = False
        print "Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length", len(aList) #Debug Data
        print "input List=", aList #Debug Data

        for item2 in aList[firstItem + 1:lastItem + 1:]:
            #Compare first item with next
            print "Comparing item1, item2 =", item1 , item2 #Debug Data

            """ Check if second string is reverse / palindrome or same """      
            if  item1[::-1] == item2 or item1 == item2:
                found = True
                saveFound = True
                print "Removing", item2 #Debug Data
                aList.remove(item2) # Remove second item matching criteria
            else:
                found = False

        """One iteration cycle is complete"""
        if saveFound == True:
            print "Starting Next Iteration" #Debug Data
            uniqLst(aList)              #Force load of new aList

    #External loop is complete exit Function
    return aList


""" Main Function """    
if __name__== "__main__":

    tmpLst1 = ["".join(x) for x in permutations('ABC', 3)]
    tmpLst2 = ["".join(x) for x in combinations('ABC', 3)]

    checkStrLst = tmpLst1 + tmpLst2

    finalList =  uniqLst(checkStrLst)
    print "========================"
    print "finalList", finalList
```

**OutPut**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 7
input List= ['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = ABC ACB
Comparing item1, item2 = ABC BAC
Comparing item1, item2 = ABC BCA
Comparing item1, item2 = ABC CAB
Comparing item1, item2 = ABC CBA
Removing CBA
Comparing item1, item2 = ABC ABC
Removing ABC
Starting Next Iteration
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 5
input List= ['ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB BAC
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB BCA
Removing BCA
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB CAB
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB ABC
Starting Next Iteration
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 4
input List= ['ACB', 'BAC', 'CAB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB BAC
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB CAB
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 4
input List= ['ACB', 'BAC', 'CAB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = BAC BAC
Removing BAC
Comparing item1, item2 = BAC CAB
Removing CAB
Comparing item1, item2 = BAC ABC
Starting Next Iteration
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = CAB ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = BAC ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = BCA ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = CAB ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = ACB ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = BAC ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = BCA ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = CAB ABC
Starting Next for Loop : Loop Length 2
input List= ['ACB', 'ABC']
Comparing item1, item2 = CBA ABC
Removing ABC
Starting Next Iteration
========================
finalList ['ACB']
>>>
```

Comment: 'ABC' is not a palindrome of  'CBA' (anagram maybe). 'ABCD' is not the reverse of 'CDBA' (still anagram).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have updated details with correct information for both palindrome and reverse. The logic of checking against reverse of string will take care of both though. It was late at night and my brain was fused. Appreciate the catch.

Comment: :) actually, anagram check catches all 3 of 'em

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I tried to get your code to work while changing as little as possible. Bottom line is, I don't think you can get away without changing your aList as you have to somehow track your status in each recursive step.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

""" Process list to generate Unique strings matching given criteria """
def uniqLst(aList, finalList):

    """ Iterate through outer loop to compare each string until End of Loop """

    # Terminate if length is 0
    if(len(aList) == 0):
        return

    # Initialize local values
    found = False
    item1 = aList[0];

    # Go through list and compare with first item
    for item2 in aList[1:len(aList)]:

        """ Check if second string is reverse / palindrome or same """
        if item1[::-1] == item2 or item1 == item2:
            found = True
            print "Removing", item2 #Debug Data
            aList.remove(item2) # Remove second item matching criteria

    # If no item matches, add first item to final list
    if found != True:
        temp = aList.pop(0)
        finalList.append(temp)

        # Recursively call this function with updated aList
    uniqLst(aList, finalList)

    return


""" Main Function """
if __name__== "__main__":

    tmpLst1 = ["".join(x) for x in permutations('ABC', 3)]
    tmpLst2 = ["".join(x) for x in combinations('ABC', 3)]

    checkStrLst = tmpLst1 + tmpLst2

    finalList = []
    uniqLst(checkStrLst, finalList)
    print "========================"
    print "finalList", finalList
```

I added comments to help you understand what I'm doing for each step.
Let me know if this doesn't fit your requirements!

Comment: Perfect, I guess I got too much wrapped around double for loop didnt realizing I don't needs it for recursion.
Also, putting result in another list was a good idea. I was toying with that but under double loop was causing more harm than good.